# Java -> TCP -> node.js (String data transfer)

Tags: java, node.js, sockets, tcp

Client (Java)

```
Socket tcpClient = new Socket("localhost", 6000); 
String msg ="test";
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(tcpClient.getOutputStream());
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);
pw.println(msg);
pw.flush();
```

Server (node.js JavaScript)

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (c)
{ //'connection' listener
    log('Java client connected to this nodeServer');
    c.on('data', function (data)
    {
        console.log(data);   
    });
    c.on('end', function ()
    {
        console.log('nodeServer disconnected');
    });
});
server.listen(6000, function ()
{ //'listening' listener
    console.log('nodeServer listening port:6000');
});
```

Result

```
nodeServer listening port:6000

Java client connected to this nodeServer

<Buffer 74 65 73 74 0a>
```

The connection succeeded, but obviously, I need 'test' string in Result.

For the data, I use String so far to simplify my problem, however, it's ideal to be able to transfer any Objects.

Perhaps, I need to use JSON framework (for non-binary object) to send over Java/TCP, but not sure.

---

PS.
this works by simply modifying to

```
 var data1 = data.toString('utf-8');
 console.log(data1);
```

Just to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works by simply modifying to

```
 var data1 = data.toString('utf-8');
 console.log(data1);
```

Just to share.